# split paired samples based on substring

Tags: r, substring, stringr

I have two groups of paired samples that could be separated by the first two letters. I would like to make two groups based on the pairing using something like `[tn][abc]`.

```
Example of paired samples:
nb-008  ta-008
na015   ta-015
```

data:

```
    > colnames(data)
      "nb-008"  "nb-014"  "na015"   "na-018"  "ta-008"   "tc-014"  "ta-015"  "ta-018"  

  patient <- factor(sapply(str_split(colnames(data), '[tn][abc]'), function(x) x[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable with `sub`.  We match the pattern of 2 characters (`..`) from the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by `-` (if present), followed by one or more characters (`.*`) that we capture as a group (inside the brackets), and replace by the backreference (`\\1`).  This can be used to `split` the column names.

```
split(colnames(data), sub('^..-?(.*)', '\\1', colnames(data))))
#$`008`
#[1] "nb-008" "ta-008"

#$`014`
#[1] "nb-014" "tc-014"

#$`015`
#[1] "na015"  "ta-015"

#$`018`
#[1] "na-018" "ta-018"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("nb-008",  "nb-014",  "na015",   "na-018",  
            "ta-008",   "tc-014",  "ta-015", "ta-018" ) 
set.seed(24)
data <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:8, 8*5, 
               replace=TRUE), ncol=8)), v1)
```

Comment: could you just quick explain '^..-?(.*)', '\\1'

Comment: @user2300940  Sure I will add in the description

Comment: Is it possible to output this as a factor with levels (4 in this case)? as.factor(), does not work

Comment: @user2300940  Not sure I understand your question.  The output here is a `list`.  If you want to get this converted to `factor` use `lapply(res, factor, levels=nm1)` where `nm1` is the vector of factor levels.